# GitLab CI does not working : custom executor is missing RunExec

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

We have running gitlab instance and now trying to integrate Gitlab CI. To do it we followed official guide.

And installed `gitlab-runner` successfully.

> Running with gitlab-runner 13.1.0 (6214287e)  on testcicd xxxxxx
> Preparing the "custom" executor  WARNING: custom executor is missing
> RunExec  ERROR: Job failed: custom executor is missing RunExec

My `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
build1:
  tags: 
    - ci
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Do your build here"
```

Comment: It looks like there is an issue with the gitlab-runner using the custom executor. I'm not sure if you want to be using the custom executor unless you have a very specific scenario, but it seems like you're missing some [configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/custom.html#configuration) for it?